# Where do glassfish keep war file deployed from web (admin console)?

Tags: glassfish-3

I am deploying geoserver from web console but I can't find the war. Where do glassfish all those file when deploying from web?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As far as I'm concerned, glassfish does not keep the original WAR file. It's "unzipped" to a folder stored in glassfish\domains\domain1\applications. I didn't encounter such situation where WAR files would have been kept by server after deployment.
Hope I helped.

Comment: Hi, my applications directory is empty. I have 2 WAR files deployed in it. domains/domain1/applications/__internal folder is not found. I am using glassfish 4 version.

Comment: I did a full search in C: and found it at C:\Users\<<username>>\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.0.1\config\GF_4.1\domain1\applications\quercus-4.0.39

Answer (score 14):

It has been a while since the question was made but maybe this can help someone who is looking for the answer.

I found the deployed WAR files at: glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/__internal

Comment: What about the ears?

Comment: EARs are also in the same directory

Answer (score 3):

If you navigate to the glassfish config folder under domains and then open the domains.xml file you'll find a section called .  Within this section you'll find your WAR file and also an element/attribute called  whose values indicates where the deployed WAR file is expanded.